# Returning null from C# generic regardless of supplied type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing an in-memory cache of settings for our webservices. This is so that we do not have to hit the database every time we need a setting. We have a mechanism to invalidate the cache when the database is updated.

The cache is a bunch of dictionaries that contain different types, here's two of those dictionaries:

```
static readonly object StringValueCacheMutex = new object();
static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> StringValueCache = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

static readonly object IntegerValueCacheMutex = new object();
static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Int64>> IntegerValueCache = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Int64>>();
```

I would like to write a generic function that gets a value from these dictionaries, if the category/setting was not found in the dictionary it should return null to signify it was not found.

The problem is that these dictionaries contain both nullable and non-nullable types.

Here's the generic I want to have:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrNull<TValue>(
    IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TValue>> cacheDictionary,
    object cacheMutex,
    string categoryName,
    string settingName)
{
    TValue value = null;

    lock (cacheMutex)
    {
        if (cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(categoryName))
        {
            if (cacheDictionary[categoryName].ContainsKey(settingName))
            {
                value = cacheDictionary[categoryName][settingName];
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

This will not compile due to : "Cannot convert null to type parameter 'TValue' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(TValue)' instead."

The reason I want to return null and not default(TValue) is that in the case of an integer, the caller has no way of knowing if the setting value was actually 0 or of it was not found in the cache.

So my question is, is there constraints I can put on a generic that will allow me to return null regardless of the supplied type? (I'm assuming I need to use Nullable but not sure how.

Comment: Not related to your particular question, but you might consider a `ReadWriterLock` (or better a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`,) since there's probably not a good reason for multiple readers to block one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Jon Skeet's answer, you could rewrite your method to be similar to `Dictionary.TryGetValue` by returning a `bool` and have the result as an `out` parameter. You won't need to use a `Nullable<T>`.

```
public static bool GetValueOrNull<TValue>(
    IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TValue>> cacheDictionary,
    object cacheMutex,
    string categoryName,
    string settingName,
    out TValue value)
{
    lock (cacheMutex) {
        Dictionary<string, TValue> category;
        if (cacheDictionary.TryGetValue(categoryName, out category)) {
            if (category.TryGetValue(settingName, out value))
                return true; // setting was found
        }
    }

    value = default(TValue);
    return false; // setting was not found
}
```

I would also rewrite the method name to `TryGetValue`.

Answer (score 6):

No - if `TValue` is `int` then it *simply can't be null*.

This is precisely why [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) (which is what you should be using internally, instead of using `ContainsKey` and then a second lookup) returns `bool` and has an `out` parameter for the value itself.

Put it this way: suppose `TValue` is `byte`. There are 256 possible values your method could return - but there are 257 possible outcomes: the 256 possible byte values in the cache, and the possibility that it wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nullable Int64, then you can use default(TValue)

```
static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Int64?>> IntegerValueCache 
  = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Int64?>>();
```

But when attempting to cache webservice data you shouldn't use static variables, use 
[HttpContext.Current.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

As Jon wrote var of TValue can't be null
but you really can use nullable and declare generic as `G<T?> where T : struct`

so your code would be

```
public static TValue? GetValueOrNull<TValue?>(
IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TValue>> cacheDictionary,
object cacheMutex,
string categoryName,
string settingName)
{
TValue? value = null;

lock (cacheMutex)
{
    if (cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(categoryName))
    {
        if (cacheDictionary[categoryName].ContainsKey(settingName))
        {
            value = cacheDictionary[categoryName][settingName];
        }
    }
}

return value;
}
```

Comment: Using this approach you can only store value types in the dictionary. `String` is not possible because there is no such thing as `String?`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "where TValue:class" at the end of the signature of the function, so that you ensure that the TValue is a reference type, then you can use null.

Comment: Int64 isn't a class type, it's a struct type.

Comment: Using this approach you can only store reference types in the dictionary. However, `Int64` is a value type.